# Como eu faço a soma dos valores guardados na lista: pares?

Tags: python-3.x

```
matriz = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
pares = [] 
for linha in range(0, 3):
    for coluna in range(0, 3):
    matriz[linha][coluna] = int(input("Digite um valor para [{}, {}]: ".format(linha, coluna)))
    if matriz[linha][coluna] % 2 == 0:
        pares.append(matriz[linha][coluna])
```

Comment: Por favor, melhores sua pergunta. E ponha o código dentro da tag de código (Ctrl+K)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a função `sum`.

```
soma = sum(pares)
```

Comment: Vlw ae pela ajuda